# What would cause an unprompted "The system is going down for halt NOW!"

Tags: centos, unexpected-shutdown

My CentOS 6 box keeps on shutting itself down.  How best can I ascertain what's causing it to do this?  I've installed `lm_sensors` and had a look at the CPU temps shortly before it shut itself off, and I don't think they're the issue.  Beyond that I don't know where to look?!

This is what happened in /var/log/messages at the time:

```
<previous message is from when I powered the machine on>

Jan 20 21:02:52 dedicated1 init: tty (/dev/tty1) main process (3462) killed by TERM signal
Jan 20 21:02:52 dedicated1 init: tty (/dev/tty2) main process (3464) killed by TERM signal
Jan 20 21:02:52 dedicated1 init: tty (/dev/tty3) main process (3466) killed by TERM signal
Jan 20 21:02:52 dedicated1 init: tty (/dev/tty4) main process (3468) killed by TERM signal
Jan 20 21:02:52 dedicated1 init: tty (/dev/tty5) main process (3470) killed by TERM signal
Jan 20 21:02:52 dedicated1 init: tty (/dev/tty6) main process (3472) killed by TERM signal
Jan 20 21:02:54 dedicated1 abrtd: Got signal 15, exiting
Jan 20 21:02:54 dedicated1 acpid: exiting
Jan 20 21:02:55 dedicated1 ntpd[2402]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
Jan 20 21:02:55 dedicated1 init: Disconnected from system bus
Jan 20 21:02:55 dedicated1 console-kit-daemon[5523]: WARNING: no sender#012
Jan 20 21:02:55 dedicated1 rpcbind: rpcbind terminating on signal. Restart with "rpcbind -w"
Jan 20 21:02:55 dedicated1 auditd[1985]: The audit daemon is exiting.
Jan 20 21:02:55 dedicated1 kernel: type=1305 audit(1579554175.663:69): audit_pid=0 old=1985 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
Jan 20 21:02:55 dedicated1 kernel: type=1305 audit(1579554175.770:70): audit_enabled=0 old=1 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 res=1
Jan 20 21:02:55 dedicated1 kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Jan 20 21:02:55 dedicated1 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.10" x-pid="2007" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.

<next message is from when I powered the machine back on>
```

Does that mean anything useful?  If not, where should I look next?

`last -x | grep shutdown` gives:

```
shutdown system down  2.6.32-754.25.1. Tue Jan 21 12:07 - 14:50  (02:42)
shutdown system down  2.6.32-754.25.1. Mon Jan 20 23:31 - 11:55  (12:24)
shutdown system down  2.6.32-754.25.1. Mon Jan 20 21:02 - 22:58  (01:55)
shutdown system down  2.6.32-754.25.1. Mon Jan 20 20:36 - 20:48  (00:11)
shutdown system down  2.6.32-754.25.1. Mon Jan 20 15:00 - 20:02  (05:01)
shutdown system down  2.6.32-754.24.3. Thu Jan  2 08:28 - 08:31  (00:02)
```

Comment: Can you look at `var/log/acpid` and `last -x | grep shutdown`? Is it a bare metal or a VM? If it is a bare metal, maybe a power/hardware issue? If VM, maybe check the host?

Comment: It's baremetal.  I've submitted a support request for the datacenter to have a look, but nothing yet...  `/var/log/acpid` doesn't exist.  I'm adding the `last` output to the above question for formatting.